# Using aggregate functions without including them in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I had a database containing school classes and I wanted to find the grade 1, 3 and 5 classes that have the student with the lowest student ID number but I only want to return the ClassID in the result set (not the student number).

Edit: I realize now this isn't a perfect model for my real problem. Updated it to more properly reflect the problem.

The only way I've found to do this is the following:

```
SELECT 
    ClassID
FROM 
    Classes 
INNER JOIN
    Students ON Classes.ClassID = Students.ClassID
WHERE 
    Classes.Grade IN (1, 3, 5)
GROUP BY 
    Classes.ClassID
HAVING 
    MIN(StudentID) = MIN(StudentID)
```

This returns the same list of ClassIDs as the following:

```
 SELECT 
        ClassID,
        MIN(StudentID)
    FROM 
        Classes 
    INNER JOIN
        Students ON Classes.ClassID = Students.ClassID
    WHERE 
        Classes.Grade IN (1, 3, 5)
    GROUP BY 
        Classes.ClassID
```

This seems to work, but it looks funny to me. Is this the only way?

Comment: That won't do what you want...

Comment: What if the student with the lowest student ID is not in a grade 5 class?

Comment: The inner join and the where clause should prevent that.

Comment: Your HAVING clause is wrong. it's meaningless since it's comparing to identicle values. it's like writing HAVING 1=1.

Comment: So your requirement is that it is the lowest student ID for all students who are in a grade 5 class?

Comment: Yes, lowest student ID for all students in a grade 5 class.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It doesn't always evaluate to true. It is actually semantically equivalent to `MIN(StudentID) IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith I stand corrected once again. thanks

Comment: You would clarify your question and your thinking if you edited the question to provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 steps in 'get the lowest studentId in grade 5, then tell me what class s/he's in.' So I think a nested query might the simplest thing to do, something like:

```
Select ClassId 
From Students
Join 
    ( Select Classes.Grade, Min(StudentId) as StudentId
        From Classes 
        Join Students ON Classes.ClassID = Students.ClassID
        Where Classes.Grade  in (1, 3, 5)
        Group By Classes.Grade 
        ) LowestStudentIdPerGrade
    On Students.StudentId = LowestStudentIdPerGrade.StudentId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lowest student id in the three classes, use `order by` and `top`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Classes.ClassID
FROM Classes INNER JOIN
     Students
     ON Classes.ClassID = Students.ClassID
WHERE Classes.Grade IN (1, 3, 5)
ORDER BY StudentId ASC;
```

If you want this information *per class*, then use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ClassId, Grade
FROM (SELECT Classes.ClassID, Classes.Grade,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Classes.ClassID ORDER BY StudentId ASC) as seqnum
     FROM Classes INNER JOIN
          Students
          ON Classes.ClassID = Students.ClassID
     WHERE Classes.Grade IN (1, 3, 5)
    ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You don't need `group by` for this.